# Alternative 'all' method when retrieving all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a rake task to sync data from rails app to solr
I use:
`Job.all` to get all the records and process them afterwards.But what if in Job has millions of records. As far as I know the `all` method will save all records to RAM, which definitely affects performance. Is there any other way to process all records without using `all` method?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [find_in_batches](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches), this will not load all the records at once.
By default it will load the 1000 rows and also helps to reduce memory consumption.

```
2.5.1 :013 > User.find_in_batches do |group, batch|
2.5.1 :014 >     puts "Processing group ##{batch}"
2.5.1 :015?>   end
  User Load (7.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
Processing group ##<User:0x00005596f8ef44c8>
  User Load (5.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1002], ["LIMIT", 1000]]
Processing group ##<User:0x00005596f908e900>
  User Load (5.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2002], ["LIMIT", 1000]]
Processing group ##<User:0x00007f36a4f1a428>
  User Load (6.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3004], ["LIMIT", 1000]]
Processing group ##<User:0x00007f36a4b82590>
```